# c++ namespaces in a 3 file project undefined reference

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am going through C++ Primer by Stephen Prata. I have just been introduced to the concept of namespaces. I have created a simple three file project to implement my namespace. I have not implemented much code yet but enough that it should compile. However, I get the following error: undefined reference to `SALES::setSales(SALES::Sales&, double const*, int)'. I think I have not declared/included something properly. Here are my three files. Please help and thanks in advance for reading this.

```html
//sales.h

#ifndef SALES_H_
#define SALES_H_

namespace SALES
{
    const int QUARTERS = 4;
    struct Sales
    {
        double sales[QUARTERS];
        double average;
        double max;
        double min;
    };
    // copies the lesser of 4 or n items from the array ar
    // to the sales member of s and computes and stores the
    // average, maximum, and minimum values of the entered items;
    // remaining elements of sales, if any, set to 0
    void setSales(Sales & s, const double ar[], int n);

    // gathers sales for 4 quarters interactively, stores them
    // in the sales member of s and computes and stores the
    // average, maximum, and minimum values
    void setSales(Sales & s);

    // display all information in structure s
    void showSales(const Sales & s);

}

#endif

//sales.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "sales.h"
using namespace std;

// copies the lesser of 4 or n items from the array ar
// to the sales member of s and computes and stores the
// average, maximum, and minimum values of the entered items;
// remaining elements of sales, if any, set to 0
void setSales(SALES::Sales & s, const double ar[], int n)
{

}
// gathers sales for 4 quarters interactively, stores them
// in the sales member of s and computes and stores the
// average, maximum, and minimum values
void setSales(SALES::Sales & s)
{

}
// display all information in structure s
void showSales(const SALES::Sales & s)
{

}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "sales.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace SALES;

int main()
{
    Sales Bill;
    const double Bill_sales[] = {1200.23,1400.01,2357.45,4530.58};
    setSales(Bill,Bill_sales,QUARTERS);
    Sales Mary;
    setSales(Mary);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er, try adding `SALES::` to the functions . For example,

```
void SALES::setSales(SALES::Sales & s) { }
```

Comment: That did it, much obliged.

Comment: @user3713343 You're welcome. Would you mind marking me as *the best answer*?